# Concatenar cadenas de varios objetos del mismo tipo de acuerdo al valor de otra de sus propiedades

Tags: python

Esto sera un poco largo así que tratare de resumirlo...

Tengo una lista de objetos, cada objeto es de la clase siguiente:

```
class Ponente:
  def __init__(self, nombre, discurso):
    self.nombre=nombre  
    self.discurso=discurso
    ...
```

Ambos valores para cada objeto los estoy obteniendo de un documento que ha sido escrito manualmente, por lo que (en ocasiones) tienen errores de escritura. Al obtener los nombres del documento (con ayuda de una expresión regular) se obtienen de la siguiente manera:
(Ejemplo solo con un nombre, hay varios nombres más con errores de escritura)

```
JESSICA FLORES
JESICA FLORES
JESSICAFLORES
...
```

He creado una función que recolecta el contenido de un nombre, aún estando mal escrito. Y por cada nombre he instanciado un objeto de la clase de arriba, por lo que ahora tengo (siguiendo el ejemplo) tres objetos con nombre ligeramente distinto, que en realidad es solo una persona. Lo que ahora quiero hacer es concatenar el contenido que cada objeto tiene en su propiedad `discurso` en un solo objeto, los tres objetos están dentro de una lista con varios nombres más en la misma situación y por supuesto estos nombres no están uno detrás de otro dentro de la lista. He estado un día y medio pensando en una solución pero no he tenido éxito :(

He estado intentando con el siguiente código pero no funciona muy bien:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def similar(a, b):
  return SequenceMatcher(None,a , b).ratio()

aux = ponentes # ponentes es la lista donde están los objetos
ponente_final = []
for e in ponentes: 
  aux.remove(e)
  for j in aux:
    similitud = similar(e.nombre, j.nombre)
    if similitud >= 0.9 and similitud != 1:
      e.discurso += ' ' + j.discurso
  else:
    ponente_final.append(e)
```

Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Ese es un problema interesante ...

Answer (score 1):

Cambia

```
if similitud >= 9.0 and similitud != 1:
```

por esto

```
if similitud >= .9 and similitud != 1:
```

El resultado de `SequenceMatcher(None,a , b).ratio()` está en el rango 0 a 1.

Comment: Me equivoque al formular esa parte, en realidad justo como tu lo pusiste es como lo tengo en mi código. Ya lo corregí en la pregunta.